# Swift: Avoid Realm Object to deallocate a dynamic var each time is accessed

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I need a model object to initialize (and keep synchronized) some data structures for optimization purposes.

```
Model{
    var shareInstance 
    var objA : ClassA

    var init(){
        objA.objB.configureNonRealmProperty() //1
    }
}

ClassA:Object{
    dynamic var objB : ClassB
}

ClassB : Object{
    var non-realm-property 
    convenience init(...){ //2
       configureNonRealmProperty()  
    }
    configureNonRealmProperty(){}
}
```

Not letting the swift implementation of Realm neither subclass Object multiple times, nor override the init method (this is ridiculous, if only had known before...) i need to find a way to execute a method of class whenever objB is called.

**Problem**: whenever i access objB this is reallocated from the DB by realm independently if i keep a reference to it (a dynamic reference) or not, as a conseguence it does not matter if i:
  (1) call the method `configureNonRealmProperty()` directly on the object on creation 
  (2) create a custom initializer and do it there
the objB is ALWAYS deallocated and reallocated at each interaction (through one of the private and not overridable Object initializers), i would have to call the damn `configureNonRealmProperty()` each time, which does not make any sense.

**Question**: how can i avoid a Realm Object reference by a dynamic var in another realm object to be deallocated/reallcoated each time it is accessed?

The only solution i can come up with is to have a two-layered model and kick the persistence away in the second one, but at this point i would not see any utility anymore for Realm loosing all of the (at this point already few) advantages.

An alternative would be to have at least constructors/destructors callbacks from realm, but still defeating my optimizations purpose.

Personal consideration: Realm is definitely not flexible and complete enough to be such a pervasive framework (forcing to subclass it's own object instead of a protocol, not letting create object hierarchies, dynamic on all vars, no init override, ecc)

Comment: Sorry you feel that way! Realm is built on a C++ engine that uses Objective-C runtime reflection to override the property accessors it controls. This is necessary for its 'live object' capabilities. There's no way to not require objects be a subclass of `Object` at the moment. Things might be more flexible if the Swift version of Realm could be built on top of the engine directly, but that can't even be considered until Swift supports C++ interoperability.

Comment: This *might* potentially be a bug. I'd recommend reporting it over at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues

Comment: Thanks @TiM , i will asap. And yes, i know that sadly most of Realm issues are due to swift language shortcomings. OT: Could you point me out some resources or explain briefely why is c++ interop needed eventually? Thank you.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for understanding! Haha yeah, and with the Swift standard ever changing, we're always wary of trying to make the experience better (Or at the very least, avoiding regressions!). The core Realm engine was originally built as a C++ library; which is how it's able to be run cross-platform on Android, as well as to get native level performance. Unfortunately, that means Swift interop needs to be abstracted through Realm Objective-C in order to work (Which is also why the 'dynamic' keyword is necessary).

Comment: There's definitely a lot of enthusiasm behind making Realm Swift work without needing the Objective-C runtime. That would mean deploying it to Swift on Linux would become feasible.

Comment: Very very clear @TiM thank you, and sorry, the question was indeed a bit of a rant, gonna edit as i have time.